# Question about trilling

Tags: piano

how trill works, the first trill is from f sharp to g sharp and the next trill is from d sharp to e so it is confusing me how trill works, Do we play the next sharp or the next note? could explain tr to me

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a trill?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38422/what-is-a-trill)

Comment: The indicated duplicate question answers this post in its first sentence. "The trill is initially performed between the note written and the note above it according to the key signature."

Answer (score 1):

Unless marked otherwise a trill is always to the next higher diatonic note. The F# trills to G# and the D# to the next diatonic note: E.